# Error Code: 3109. Generated column 'cod_user' cannot refer to auto-increment column

Tags: java, mysql

Lo que deseo hacer es lo siguiente que el id que se genera automaticamente, se convierta en el codigo ejemplo, id = 1 / cod = C001.

Logre hacerlo mediante SQL Server con el siguiente codigo

```
CREATE TABLE [Productos](
id_user int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
cod_user AS ('U'+right('000'+CONVERT(varchar,ID),(3))),
nom_user varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Pero debo hacerlo en MySQL, en el cual lo he realizado de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE prueba(
id_user     int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
cod_user    char(5) AS ('U' + RIGHT('0000'+ convert(id_user, char(4)),(4))),
nom_user    varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ;
```

Se genera el siguiente error

```
Error Code: 3109. Generated column 'cod_user' cannot refer to auto-increment column.
```

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a @IndiraRivas logre encontrar la respuesta.

Les comparto la solución para aportar en la comunidad y ayudar alguno que tenga el mismo problema:

```
CREATE TABLE cod
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE prueba
(
    id_user     int auto_increment primary KEY, 
    cod_user    VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    nom_user    varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_PRUEBA_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON prueba
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO cod VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.cod_user = CONCAT('U', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 5, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO prueba (nom_user) VALUES ('Axel'), ('Jose'), ('Daniel');

select * from prueba;
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido @Axel Davis Alva, `primary key` es una sentencia separada de `auto_increment`, la sintaxis sería así

```
CREATE TABLE prueba(
   id_user INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   cod_user char(5) AS ('U' + RIGHT('0000'+ convert(id_user, char(4)),(4))),
   nom_user varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (id_user)
);
```

> Ojo, toma en cuenta el tamaño de longitud de `int`, así como de
>   `char`, qué pasa cuando sea el id número 100 (C00100), necesitas
>   agregar más caracteres, debes anticiparte ante esos casos

Comment: Muchas gracias por la cordial bienvenida.

Comment: Trate de realizar el procedimiento, según tu sugerencia, pero me sigue indicando el mismo error

Comment: Okey, yo creo que no es problema de la síntaxis en si, es la forma en que lo estás concatenando cod_user, necesitas un disparador externo, en este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix) lo hace @patern

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente en el enlace encontre la solucion.

Comment: Excelente, sería bueno que editaras tu post con la solución, de cómo quedo finalmente tu insert para que les sirva a más personas